# Batch Normalization in tensorflow at inference time

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

```
My x is -1.593087986111640930e-02,
beta is 4.061257466673851013e-02,  
moving mean is -1.356904511339962482e-03, 
moving variance is 4.480824827624019235e-06 
gamma is false so result will not scale 
epsilon = 0.001

x_hat = (x - moving_mean) / square_root_of(moving_variance + epsilon) 
y = gamma * x_hat + beta
```

when I calculated manually then y gives as -0.4192285

but in tensorflow y gives as -6.781823635101318359e-01

Why this is happening? Is this correct equation at the inference time for batch normalization in tensorflow? Here I am using tensorflow.contrib.slim.batch_norm function.

Comment: What do you mean "gamma is False"?  Gamma should be a number, not a boolean

Comment: When gamma is passing to the batch_norm function as a parameter at that time it set as false so gamma will ignored in equation.

Answer (score 2):

Your epsilon is much too large. Take a look at your moving variance, it's around 1e-6, and you're adding 1e-3 to it as epsilon!

When you change epsilon to something more appropriate (think 1e-9) it becomes closer to what TF provides. The only reason people add epsilon is to avoid dividing by 0, which is even noted on the tf.batch_normalization page, so 1e-3 is way too high:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/batch_normalization

Comment: "When you change epsilon to something more appropriate (think 1e-9) it becomes closer to what TF provides"  How TF provides the epsilon?

Comment: It depends which function you are using and which tensorflow version. You'll have to find it on the github page (for example, something like https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py). Funnily enough, some of those functions use 1e-3.